# Firestore show displayName user with reference UID

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I need to print the `displayName` of a user but having the UID as a reference. Let's see if I explain myself well.

I have this collection where I store the `users`:

```
users: { // collection
  VQjobtFDlicEQtJHSVoLtPsm5713: { // docID
    displayName: "Paco"
    email: "paco@mail.com"
    usuarioID: "rvHTAIRaOCP2SsLo4vV37E9FwmD2" // string
  }
  docID: {
  ...
  }
}
```

Then I have this collection where I have stored the UID of the user who created the document:

```
avisos: {
  docID: {
    ...
    usuarioID: "VQjobtFDlicEQtJHSVoLtPsm5713" // string
  }
}
```

When I print the document from the collection 'avisos', is there a way that instead of appearing the UID of the user, its name appears? that is `displayName`?

For now I am calling the collection in this way:

**service.ts**

```
getAvisos() {
  this.avisos = this.afs.collection('avisos').valueChanges();
  return this.ubicaciones
}
```

**components.ts**

```
traerAvisos() {
  this.avisos = this.fs.getAvisos();
}
```

**component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let aviso of avisos | async">
    {{ aviso.usuarioID }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm stating the obvious, but you'll have to query for that other document in `users` for its data you want to display.

Comment: What I try is to show only the collection `avisos` inside them the user